# create n different vectors using user input c++

Tags: c++

I was trying to create N different vectors where N would be the user value.

I tried something like this

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        vector<int> v[i];
```

However when i try to use the vectors i get error like this

> error: ‘v’ was not declared in this scope

I think the vectors that i created are in the scope of that loop , i might need to declare them outside but if i do , how can i iterate and create n different vectors?

How do i achieve this solution, can it be achieved?

Comment: Create a `vector<vector<int>>`. And do it outside the loop. `push_back` a new vector inside the loop

Comment: @AndyG that worked , do you want to write an answer?

Comment: `vector<vector <int>> v;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        vector<int> vec;
        v.push_back(vec);
    }`

Comment: @BOTJr. you can further add another for loop if you want to add values to each vector

Comment: @BOTJr. Nah. Go ahead and answer your own question. Feel the victory!

Comment: @BOTJr.: if you are going to default-construct the nested vectors being pushed, and not populate them, then you don't need a loop at all: `vector<vector <int>> v(N);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A couple things to note.**

`std::vector` has a `push_back()` method that takes in what your vector is defined as. So if you make `vector<int>` then `push_back(would_take_an_int_here)`.

You can read up on vectors and their properties here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

As far as what you are looking for, take the above example and let's expand on it.

So you want a vector of vectors? That means `push_back(needs_to_take_a_vector)`

**Let's start with the technical code snippet:**

```
//First we define the vector

vector<int> x; //this is a vector of integers

vector<vector<int>> x; //this is a vector of integer vectors

//Now we want to let the user enter the amount of vectors needed.   
//We would probably want a for-loop, because it is a count based loop and we    
//know exactly how much the user wants to enter.

for(int i = 0; i < user_input; i++) {
    vector<int> my_vec;
    //This allows the vector<int> to be populated
    //before being pushed back to x, not necessary though.
    my_vec.push_back(i);
    x.push_back(my_vec);
}
```

One neat thing I would try to do after the loop, just to see if you actually did fulfill what you wanted in your vector, is this:

```
//notice there is a .size() function for vectors to see how many elements are 
//inside the vector.
std::cout << "My user asked for " << user_input << " vectors, and my vectors size is " << my_vec.size() << " elements big" << endl;
```

I hope some of this explains certain parts and goes a little more beyond what you would like so you can understand!